# In VMware Workstation's live boot menu, can I select a specific hard drive?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware Workstation 16.2, and there is a small deficiency. I don't know how to select a specific hard drive to boot.

[image]

Of course, there is workaround. Stop the VM, From menu "VM", select "Power on to firmware", then choose a specific hard drive there. But it is a bit inconvenient.

[image]

Since in Boot Menu, there is a '+'(plus sign) before "Hard Drive", I think there should be a way to expand the list. I tried space key, right-arrow key, and '+' character, no luck yet.

Comment: I have VMware Workstation V17 here. There is no VMware Live Boot menu. So I think you need to set up new machine and that is where you can assign a hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

This is the subject of the Support article from 2020
[Boot menu +Hard Drive submenu not opening issue](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Boot-menu-Hard-Drive-submenu-not-opening-issue/td-p/1872052).

The answers by user continuum who has the status of "Immortal"
on the forum were:

> Make that change in the Boot-page of the BIOS.
>
> Regard the + in the boot menu as nothing more as a reminder that the
> Hard Drive option in the boot menu is preset to your favorite boot
> disk
>
> If you want to switch your favorite boot-disk you have to do that in
> the BIOS
>
> Start with "boot into firmware" then 4 times "arrow right" and you are
> there - make selection - F10
>
> done

To boot into the firmware is actually done in menu
*VM > Power > Power On to Firmware*.

Seems like it's the only solution.

Comment: Well, it's a pity not seeing the desired functionality, bcz nearly all "real" PC BIOS(especially those by AMI) today support quick hard drive selection from the live boot menu.

Comment: You might possibly open a feature request for VMware.